# Vaadin Heartbeat causing OIDC State Mismatch after Keycloak Login in Wildfly Elytron

Tags: vaadin, wildfly

After logging in, the page throws a bad_request error. The issue arises from Vaadin sending a heartbeat request after redirecting to the Single Sign-On (SSO), subsequently overriding the state parameter.

Here's the sequence of events:

1. Upon loading the URL, the Wildfly Elytron HTTP OIDC submodule captures the request.
2. The submodule identifies the request as unauthenticated and redirects it to the Single Sign-On (SSO) server (Keycloak).
3. After the redirect Vaadin sends a heartbeat request, overwriting the originally generated state parameter.
4. After a successful login on Keycloak, when the application is redirected back, a bad_request error occurs due to the mismatched state parameters.

Is there any idea on how to prevent Vaadin from sending the heartbeat request before authentication?

Versions:

```
Vaadin: 24.2.5
Keycloak: 22.0.4
Wildfly: 30.0.0.Final
Wildfly Elytron OIDC
```

Stack:
Wildfly, Vaadin, Keycloak, Docker.

Comment: Why is the application loaded and then the heart-beat blocked by security?

Comment: @cfrick The heart-beat is not blocked, The website loads then Wildfly redirects to the SSO then Vaadin sends heart-beat. The heart-beat is not blocked.